# Is it possible to move content from one div to another purely via CSS?

Tags: html, css

#### CSS

```
<style>
#layer1 {
    height: 60px;
    background-color:#00FF00;   
}
#layer2 {
    height: 60px;
    background-color:#FFFFCC;

}
</style>
```

#### HTML

```
<div id="layer1">
This is the first div.
</div>
<div id="layer2">
This is the second div.
</div>
```

#### Question

If do not change the structure of this HTML, and only change the CSS code, is it possible to move content from one div to the other? I want to move the text *"This is the first div."* to *layer2*, to make the text: *"This is the first div."* show at the left side of *layer2*, and make the text: *"This is the second div."* to show at the right side of *layer2*.

Comment: _and make text:"This is the second div." to show at the right side of layer2_ - Did you mean to have that show at the right side of **layer 1**?

Comment: You can use CSS to position the elements differently. This would have the same affect as moving the content from one div to the other. Pretty much you would just swap there positions with css. My guess is that you are wanting to do something a little bit more though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is vulnerable to understand what you are asking so some said not possible without javascript. But as far as I understand your question is to make `float: left;` to your #layer1, and #layer2 if this is likely to this

> This is the first div. This is the second div.

```
#layer1, #layer2{
float: left;
}
```

If likely to this use float: left; to #layer2 and float: right; to #layer1

> This is the second div.This is the first div.

```
#layer2{
float: left;
}
#layer1{
float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS3 `content` property. However, this isn't recommended as it makes your code look, well, really weird. You could just move the content manually and it wouldn't make a difference. Unless I don't understand what you're saying, in which case, please clarify. If you want to make it responsive, then just use Javascript instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you want the elements to show up like this...

> This is the first div. This is the second div.

... instead of like this...

> This is the first div.
>
> This is the second div.

... then you don't need to "move content" between the two to do this. Use the `display:inline-block;` property as in the example below, and the div elements you're using will sit on the same line, instead of each one starting on a new line.

```css
#layer1,
#layer2 {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible to do that without touch html structure or using javascript.

It would have been possible only if there was a way to select text element inside div in css, then we could push it down and that would extend the other div to accommodate it.